# Some GSM devices crashing with CDMA SignalStrength error on Android

Tags: android, gsm, telephony, telephonymanager, lte

My Android app monitors cellular signal strengths.  On CDMA devices, it works without any problems. On *many* GSM devices, it works without any problems.  However, on *some* GSM devices, I am getting force closes with the following error message:

**java.lang.ClassCastException: android.telephony.cdma.CdmaCellLocation cannot be cast to android.telephony.gsm.GsmCellLocation**

I am fairly certain that this issue occurs on some Samsung devices in the US when they receive a 4G LTE signal; I believe it occurs on other devices and countries as well. I am still trying to determine the exact service providers and devices involved.

Here is the relevant snippet of code from MyService.java; I have marked the line referenced by the error message with `//********`:

```
public void onCreate() {
    tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    ...
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent in, int flags, int startId) {
    signalStrengthListener = new SignalStrengthListener();
    ((TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(signalStrengthListener, SignalStrengthListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS | SignalStrengthListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE | SignalStrengthListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE | SignalStrengthListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION);
    return START_STICKY;
    ...
}

public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
    isGSM = signalStrength.isGsm();
    if (isGSM == true) {
        GCellLoc = (GsmCellLocation)tm.getCellLocation();    //********
    ...
}
```

Not sure why is anything from `android.telephony.cdma` is appearing if this code should only be triggered when `isGSM` returns true. Perhaps when an LTE signal is detected, that puts the phone in some sort of dual CDMA/GSM mode as far as the Android API is concerned? I have not been able to find any documentation of similar behavior. How can I handle this in my code? Thanks.

Comment: You need to dig deep into the Android source for the `telephony` to find out how to determine which is which, i.e. CDMA, GSM, EVO ... and handle the case appropriately...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot explain why it is happening.  I have some theories, but you have similar ones.

While you sort out the reason, you can deal with issue pragmatically. You know that sometimes even though you are getting a GSM `SignalStrength` in your callback, sometimes on some devices you get a CDMA `CellLocation` from `TelephonyManager` and write your code to handle that case using `instanceOf` instead of relying on `.isGSM()` from the `SignalStrength`.

```
CellLocation cellLoc = tm.getCellLocation();
if(cellLoc instanceof GsmCellLocation) {
   GCellLoc = (GsmCellLocation) cellLoc;
   // do work 
}
```